# Recommendations on creating user-objects on system database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker, event-notification

I want to setup a bunch of Event Notifications on SQL Server using Service Broker for our production database.

I've setup a new database on my testing machine, and everything works well.
The problem is that I'd rather not have to deploy a whole database for this notification purposes and I can't use one of the user databases already in place (that would be a mess, anyway).

If possible, I'd preferably deploy the notification objects on `master`, but first I'd like to be sure this is actually a good idea (if it actually is).

From [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx):

> Do not create user objects in master. If you do, master must be backed up more frequently.

*Books Online* recommends I do not create user objects in `master`, but in this case, I don't think it's that much of a problem since I don't really care if I eventually lose some notification data. Besides, we already do backup our `master` database frequently.

Should I use the `master` database or something else in this case?

Is there something I should know about the `master` database, Service Broker or Event Notifications before setting this up?

Comment: Don't put user objects in master.

Comment: I've seen it both ways.  I think user objects in master are prone to be forgotten, whereas a DBA database that contains those objects you use to enable you to do your job is more self-documenting.

Comment: @JNK care to elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a few questions about this implementation that I would want to know before continuing:

1. What happens if, somehow, microsoft creates an object with the exact same name in a new version?
2. If databases are migrated to a new server, how will anyone know that there's something in master to migrate?
3. What happens if your objects corrupt the master database?
4. What adverse affects would having extra data in master have on the instance?
5. What would happen if an in-place upgrade was performed on this instance? (ie, upgrading 2008 to 2008 R2)
6. How would restoring the entire instance from backups be affected?

Most of these I don't know the answer to, but they're questions that come up when I contemplate putting objects in master.

Comment: That was the kind of answer I was looking for! Indeed, very valid and good questions. Much more useful than a "don't put user objects in master" ;) But stupid people like to make themselves look smart. Thank you!